# App isn't responding right now. MalformedResponse - Could not find a RichResponse or SystemIntent in the platform response

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to get through the codelabs tutorial for Google Actions and running into some trouble. I'm on "Build Actions for the Assistant (Level 2)".

When I try to test the action in the simulator, I get "My test app isn't responding right now. Try again soon."

There is nothing in the request or response tabs. Here is the debug tab output:

```
{
  "response": "My test app isn't responding right now. Try again soon.",
  "expectUserResponse": false,
  "conversationToken": "EvwCS2o5Wk...",
  "audioResponse": "//NExAASeH...",
  "ssmlMarkList": [],
  "debugInfo": {
    "sharedDebugInfoList": []
  },
  "visualResponse": {
    "visualElementsList": [
      {
        "displayText": {
          "content": "My test app isn't responding right now. Try again soon."
        }
      }
    ],
    "suggestionsList": [],
    "agentLogoUrl": ""
  },
  "clientError": 0,
  "is3pResponse": true,
  "clientOperationList": [],
  "projectName": ""
}
```

My code:

```
'use strict';

// Import the Dialogflow module from the Actions on Google client library.
const {
    dialogflow,
    Permission,
    Suggestions,
} = require('actions-on-google');

// Import the firebase-functions package for deployment.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Instantiate the Dialogflow client.
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'favorite color'.
// The intent collects a parameter named 'color'.
app.intent('favorite color', (conv, {color}) => {
  const luckyNumber = color.length;
  // Respond with the user's lucky number and end the conversation.
  if (conv.data.userName) {
    conv.close(`${conv.data.userName}, your lucky number is ${luckyNumber}.`);
  } else {
    conv.close(`Your lucky number is ${luckyNumber}.`);
  };
});

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
  const options = {
    context: 'Hi there, to get to know you better',
    permissions: ['NAME'],
  };
  conv.ask(new Permission(options));
});

// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'actions_intent_PERMISSION'. If user
// agreed to PERMISSION prompt, then boolean value 'permissionGranted' is true.
app.intent('ask permission', (conv, params, permissionGranted) => {
  // If they didn't give me permission to use their name...
  const options = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green'];
  if (!permissionGranted) {
    conv.ask("Ok, no worries. What\'s your favorite color?");
    conv.ask(new Suggestions(options));
  } else {
    // Otherwise, they gave me permission to use it
    conv.data.userName = conv.user.name.display;
    conv.ask(`Thanks, ${conv.data.userName}. What's your favorite color?`);
    conv.ask(new Suggestions(options));
  };
});

// Set the DialogflowApp object to handle the HTTPS POST request.
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

There is also nothing in the "Error" tab. I've tried hunting down the meaning of `clientError: 0` to see if that helps to no avail. I've also tried hunting down the MalformedResponse error, but I'm not getting a lot of helpful information.

I've tried all kinds of moving code around or re-writing it and nothing changes the error message. I have no idea why it's breaking.

The logs here (https://console.cloud.google.com) for this action say:

```
MalformedResponse: ErrorId: a5421d80-def5-42ef-ba55-8ac95a879e14. Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of invalid platform response. : Could not find a RichResponse or SystemIntent in the platform response for agentId: 6edfe023-05da-4726-9ee7-6469f0a5fb3d and intentId: 8ad48133-dd71-496c-b5af-d4ec19e88309
```

I've tried hunting that down and can't find much helpful information about it.

Another thing I have noticed is the logs for this function at https://console.firebase.google.com don't seem to be updating. The last log I have is on 6/2, when the function first broke. I have no idea why it won't update. If I run `firebase functions:log`, I'll have more recent entries that look like:

```
2019-06-16T22:20:20.246Z I : 
2019-06-16T22:20:21.895Z N dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment: 
2019-06-16T22:21:01.674Z N dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment: 
2019-06-16T22:27:45.629Z I : 
2019-06-16T22:27:47.249Z N dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment: 
2019-06-16T22:28:15.351Z N dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment: 
2019-06-16T22:59:06.793Z I : 
2019-06-16T22:59:08.488Z N dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment: 
2019-06-16T22:59:49Z N dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment:
```

At one point, those logs said "Undefined" next to `dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment:`, but something changed and I don't know what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've exhausted every option I can think of at this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured it out. I'm not sure what changed, but I think it's the migration from V1 to V2 in Dialog Flow (so the tutorial wasn't really correct) and I was looking in the wrong github docs for help.

This line...

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Needed to be changed to...

```
exports.fulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I had a feeling it had to do with my deployment to Firebase, but what put me on the right track was checking out this page: https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs

Specifically, the section talking about frameworks and exporting to the appropriate one.

Hope this helps anyone else in a similar situation :)